# Graphical presentation of GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql

Is there a way to provide visual diagram (UML like) of GraphQL Schema design?

Background:
I already have a schema design with me, which is to be converted into GraphQL API. However, before starting GraphQL development, I want to create visual representation of schema that I have. Diagram should essentially show atleast Query Types and Relations, which will help developer knowing what to develop in GraphQL.

Is there a way or standards?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want. Do you want a diagram given _the schema_ that you have developed (what kind of schema is it, by the way)? or you want a diagram, given a GraphQL schema?

Comment: It is the former; I want to create a diagram given the DB schema. The output diagram to act as an input for a GraphQL developer to know what I am expecting in GraphQL schema (like query types and relations). Question is to know if there is any standard diagram by which I can provide my requirements to GraphQL developer.

Comment: GraphQL schema and DB schema don't directly correlate to each other. It's possible that GraphQL schema flattens many things that are not in DB schema. I haven't seen anything like that you need.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for sharing your view...

Comment: You can use any diagramming tool. Personally I used Omnigraffle (OSX Only), but you can use Visio (Windows), or any of the numerous online diagramming apps (e.g. draw.io, etc). 

I focused my diagram on just the query types and their relationships. All in, the resulting GraphQL API has over 200 types and diagramming it first helped guide both my GraphQL schema design and made it a lot easier to keep everything straight when I built out my resolvers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out this tool: https://github.com/sheerun/graphqlviz

In my experience using it on real-world GraphQL schemas the output can get really large but I think it may do what you are asking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply. And the tool looks to be useful for my other requirements. However, my current requirement is to create GraphQL diagram from the DB schema I know (I don't have GraphQL API yet, it is yet to be developed). I am happy to create diagram manually, but then other question is to know if there are any standards to show GraphQL diagram. (like we have class diagram, sequence diagram using UML tool)

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a standard practice for this yet. One option would be to write your schema using the GraphQL schema language and then load it with blank resolvers using a library like graphql-tools https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tools. You could then run the graphqlviz tool on it to automatically generate the diagram.

Comment: Yes, looks to be the closest solution to this problem. Will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) supports visual definition of GraphQL Schema, incl. types, interfaces, enums, inputs and relations.

Answer (score 1):

you can visualize the GraphQL schema with graphql voyager
https://ivangoncharov.github.io/graphql-voyager/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: +1 this is what I was looking for, it's free, can be deployed locally and can be used as a dependency too [https://github.com/IvanGoncharov/graphql-voyager](https://github.com/IvanGoncharov/graphql-voyager)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is a 2023 answer. I needed a way to create UML and ER diagrams based on a graphql schema created using AWS Amplify and this turned out to create them beautifully: https://app.graphqleditor.com

Comment: If a question can be answered with a link it should be closed and deleted instead of answered.

Comment: FYI: This service is not free (you get 14 days trial)